# Java MySQL Connection not closing

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

I am using a Java application front end to connect and interact with a database on a MySQL 5.6 server. Using the JDBC connector from MySQL I am having issues with connections made to the server not closing when con.close() is called. The connections are all dropped when the application is closed though. The following is the dao class used to make queries.

```
package binaparts.dao;

import java.sql.*;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import binaparts.properties.*;
import binaparts.util.ToJSON;

public class DBConnect {

protected Statement st = null;
protected ResultSet rs = null;
protected Connection con = null;    
protected PreparedStatement pst = null;
private String configFilePath = "config.properties";
public DBConnect(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private Connection getDBConnection() throws Exception{

    ConfigurationManager configProps = new ConfigurationManager(configFilePath);
    String host = configProps.getProperty("host");
    String port = configProps.getProperty("port");
    String database = configProps.getProperty("database");
    String user = configProps.getProperty("user");
    String password = configProps.getProperty("password");

    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql" + "://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database, user, password);
    }catch(SQLException SQLex){
        con = null;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        con = null;
    }finally{
        try{rs.close();} catch(Exception ex) { /*ignore*/}
        try{st.close();} catch(Exception ex) { /*ignore*/}
        try{pst.close();} catch(Exception ex) { /*ignore*/}
    }
return con;
}
```

The next bit of code is a method to verify the user of the application with the database. There are some System.out.println() statements to track the con variable through the process.

```
public boolean verifyUser() throws Exception {

    ConfigurationManager config = new ConfigurationManager(configFilePath);
    String username = config.getProperty("appUser");
    String password = config.getProperty("appPassword");
    boolean userCheck = false;
    try{
        if(con == null){
        System.out.println("there is not a connection");
        }
        if(con != null){
            System.out.println("there is a connection");
        }
        con = getDBConnection();
        if(con == null){
            System.out.println("get connection did not work");
        }
        if(con != null){
            System.out.println("get connection did work");
        }
        JSONObject temp = queryReturnUser(username).getJSONObject(0);
        con.close();
        String un = null;
        try{
            un = temp.get("username").toString();
        }catch(Exception ex){un = " ";}

        String pw = null;
        try{
            pw = temp.get("password").toString();
        }catch(Exception ex){pw = " ";}

        if(username.equals(un)){
            if(password.equals(pw)){
                userCheck = true;
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){/*ignore*/}
    finally{
        try{
            if(con == null){
                System.out.println("connection was terminated before finally");
            }
            if(con != null){
                System.out.println("connection was not terminated before finally");
                System.out.println("trying again...");
                con.close();
            }
            if(con != null){
                System.out.println("there is a connection still");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
return userCheck;
}
```

The output from running that method is:

> there is not a connection
>
> get connection did work
>
> connection was not terminated before finally
>
> trying again...
>
> there is a connection still
>
> If I change the con.close(); to con = null; then I get the output:
>
> there is not a connection
>
> get connection did work
>
> connection was terminated before finally

So the connection is successfully terminating at that point, but I feel like this is not the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `con.isClosed()` rather than `con==null` for your check. Just because you've closed a `Connection` doesn't mean your reference to the object itself will be `null`.

Comment: +1 See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isClosed()

Comment: after checking with con.isClosed(), it is working correctly, but when watching the connections with the MySQL Workbench monitoring the server, I can still see that the connections are are still there.

Comment: Like someone said below, that might be pooling on the server's side - that connection could be hanging around waiting to be reopened or waiting for another connection to take its place.

Answer (score 2):

Closing the connection has nothing to do with the object `con` being null. Your program is probably working and you had your connection closed. Your object `con` will only be null if you force it

```
...
if(con != null){
    System.out.println("connection was not terminated before finally");
    System.out.println("trying again...");
    con.close();
    con = null;
}
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling the `close()` method on a `Connection` object doesn't mean that the `Connection` object will be `null` at the end of execution of the `close()` method.

If you want to test if your connection has been closed successfully then you should call the `isClosed()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getDBConnection()` method is returning a closed connection. So you will never be able to use that connection. Not sure what is the logic of closing the connection in `getDBConnection()` method.

You should have a different method to close the connection.

Comment: The method doesn't actually return a closed connection. Its only set to close if during the try block something fails.